My data from child component is not showing up in the parent component
I have a json file, then I create a card component where that data would be displayed, then I create a parent component and template where I want to iterate through the data and generate a number of cards. However, the data doesn't show up when I call it through the card component.
Here is the Card component
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {


@Input() mydata!: {title: string, description: string};
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}


Here is the Card template for that card component;
<span class="flex gap-4 items-center">
        <svg class="iconsboxed" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M13.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V11H2V3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zm-11-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1 3.5V12h14V3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 13.5 2zM0 12.5h16a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5h-13A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 12.5"/>
        </svg>
        <span class="text-lg">{{mydata.title}}</span>
    </span>

    <p class="text-sm text-gray-400 py-4">{{mydata.description}}
    </p>


Now, this is the parent component;
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css']
})
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  projData!: any


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
   
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<any>('../assets/data.json').subscribe(mydata =>{
      this.projData = mydata;
      console.log(this.projData)
    })
  }

}


And this is the parent template;
<div class="flex items-center justify-center bg-background2 h-full w-full mb-0 text-gray-100 ">
    <div class="max-w-6xl mx-auto ">
    <header class="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <p class="text-6xl font-bold pb-[1rem]">Solutions I have crafted</p>
        <p class="text-lg pb-[2rem] text-center ">A list of the projects that I have worked on ranging from multiple languages and frameworks.</p>
    </header>
    <main class="grid grid-cols-3" >
        
        <div class="flex flex-col border-[1px] border-accent px-6 py-8 rounded-md" *ngFor= "let proj of projData">
            <app-card [mydata]="projData"></app-card>
        
            
        </div>
  
        
    </main>
    
    
</div>
</div>

However my data doesnt show up. I'm not sure what is going on.
This is the sample data.json file structure.
 [
    {
      "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "description": "The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,.",
      
    },
    {
      "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "description": "The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,.",
      
    },
    {
      "title": "Lorem Ipsum",
      "description": "The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here,.",
      
    },

  ]

When I move the array into ProjectComponent, it shows up but when I use the card component, it doesn't show up.
I am using Angular 14.
Here is the git repo should someone need to see the entire code; https://github.com/muhumuzaa/angularhumber/tree/projs
Thanks.

mistake is here
<app-card [mydata]="projData"></app-card>
replace projData to proj
It will work.
<app-card [mydata]="proj"></app-card>

Thanks but I do not have any variable called “proj” anywhere in my code base

then what is it *ngFor= "let proj of projData" you send to your @Input() mydata! all collections. But you need take it every item. You named it proj, right?

I'm so sorry. I get exactly what you are saying and it makes perfect sense. However, even after doing that, the data isn't showing up.

http.get is still an async method. That means, that projData is undefined for a short moment until the subscription callback was executed, which leads to errors, since you want to access that undefined value in CardComponent.
There are several solutions. Just to name some:

Hide CardComponent until projData is defined (@if, ngIf)
Access mydata null safe (myData?.title)
With the help of resolveJsonModule compiler option, you could import the json directly instead of using the http module, which leads to a sync behavior instead of async


Options 1 and 2 do not work still. Yet they should. I'm just wondering why the data isn't coming through even after your suggestion. If you don't mind , here is the repo, kindly take a look please, https://github.com/muhumuzaa/angularhumber/tree/projs

It`s also possible to use async pipe for work with asunchronose data:
declare Observable in the component:
public projData$ = this.http.get<any>('../assets/data.json');

Than in your template use async pipe :
<div *ngIf="projData$ | async as cards; else noCards">
   <div class="flex flex-col border-[1px] border-accent px-6 py-8 rounded-md" 
        *ngFor= "let card of cards">
       <app-card [mydata]="card"></app-card>        
   </div>
</div>

<ng-template #noCards>There no cards _)</ng-template>

Use [official angular documentation]1 to discover more about angular pipes!
Thanks!
